# degree sequence in a graph doesn't give number of degrees of a node

Tags: python, networkx

the degree sequence supposed to give number of degree for each node so if set degree sequence to degree = [4] it must give a node with 4 degrees/neighbors
here I have this example and in the plot it giving perhaps the number of degrees missing out 4 degrees. how to make the graph show the number of degrees of the degree sequence in the plot and not the number of nodes?

```
import networkx as nx

degree_seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
g = nx.configuration_model([k for k in degree_seq])
nx.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

[Graph plot of the given degree sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AuxF.png)

another plot [image: Degree_seq= [4,4]]

Comment: I don't understand your question; are you saying that something is wrong with the graph from your picture? Do you understand that a loop counts as two edges from the node?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "number of degree". It's not clear what you mean by "in the plot it giving perhaps the number of degrees missing out 4 degrees". It's not clear what you mean by "make the graph show the number of degrees of the degree sequence in the plot".

Comment: I'm saying it's wrong what is giving in the plot because the degree sequence supposed to give 4 nodes where the first node one edge is coming out, second node has  2 edges coming out, third node has3 edges coming out and the last forth node has 4 edges coming out but it's giving the something else.. please correct me if I understood this wrongly!!

Comment: I think the algorithm isn't doing what it's supposed to do!! as it is supposed to give a random graph of the given nodes' degrees but it's giving only 4 nodes, so can show me how it is supposed to give a graph with the exact out degrees for nodes

Comment: But the algorithm **is** doing what it's supposed to do. The top-right node has degree 1, the bottom-left node has degree 2, the middle node has degree 3, and the bottom-right node has degree 4. The degree 4 comes from the two edges that connect to other nodes **plus the two edges corresponding to the loop**.

Comment: [Relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)#Degree)

Comment: but if I tried to put the degree sequence as degree_seq = [4, 4] it's giving only 4 nodes with no edges, isn't supposed to give 8 nodes with 4 degrees out connecting with nodes? or setting degree_seq = [4]?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion from the comments: the algorithm works properly. The misunderstanding came from the fact that a loop actually counts as two edges rather than as one edge.

Comment: ya but if I tried to put the degree sequence as degree_seq = [4, 4] it's giving only 4 nodes with no edges, isn't supposed to give 8 nodes with 4 degrees out connecting with nodes? or setting degree_seq = [4]?

Comment: It's probably giving you a multigraph. Instead of trying to draw the graph, look at `g.edges`

Comment: @learner_from_scratch Also, if you look at `g.degree`, you should find that the single node has (or both nodes have) degree 4.

Comment: I edited my post up with the plot of degree sequence [4, 4], I don't understand why it's not working as planned!! can you please check

Comment: @learner_from_scratch Again, try looking at `g.degree` and `g.edges`

Comment: is it possible to generate a configuration model that would stick to a degree sequence but without self loops/parallel edges?

Comment: For some degree sequences, all valid configuration models will have self loops